# Is the classifying space of a non-compact Lie group equal the classifying space of the maximal compact subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces

I am currently reading the review article *Continuous cohomology of groups and classifying spaces*, by Stasheff (doi:[10.1090/S0002-9904-1978-14488-7](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1978-14488-7)), on continuous group cohomology. On page 552, it is said that $BK\simeq BG$, where $K$ is the maximal compact subgroup of the Lie group $G$. I am curious about is it true in general even if $G$ is non-compact. I don't know how to prove it. Maybe it can be shown by using Milnor's construction somehow or using spectral sequences. Is there any good reference on it? I tried to search by using keywords but in vain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

A connected Lie group $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d$ where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. This was proved by Élie Cartan in the semisimple case, and independently by Malcev and Iwasawa in the general case; see [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/53080/21564). It follows that $G$ is homotopy equivalent to $K$ and therefore $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to $BK$.

Comment: Note that the homotopy equivalence of $BG$ and $BK$ does not immediately follow from the homotopy equivalence of $G$ and $K$.  You can have homotopy equivalent (even homeomorphic) groups whose classifying spaces are not homotopy equivalent (for instance, consider non-isomorphic discrete groups of the same cardinality).  The key thing is that the inclusion map $K\to G$ is _simultaneously_ a homotopy equivalence and a homomorphism, and so it induces a map $BK\to BG$ that will also be a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: That's a very good point. Thanks @EricWofsey.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAlbanese and @EricWofsey! I think it is related to the fact the the classifying space is a functor from topological groups to topological spaces while preserving homomorphism and homotopy equivalence. I am curious about whether this property of the classifying space depends on the definition of classifying space. As I am aware of a previous [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201368/classifying-spaces-of-topological-groups-whose-underlying-spaces-are-homotopy-eq) which said that it could depend on the definition of the classifying space.